# Magento 2.2.6 undefined index on page config generator head file

Tags: magento2.2.6

Magento 2.2.6

> Notice: Undefined index: src in
>   `/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Generator/Head.php` on line
>   126

any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Most problably you have in your theme a layout file that includes some css or js file in the `head` section but it is missing the `src` attribute.
Here is an example on how it should look

```
<css src="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::css/configurable-product.css"/>
```

you are probably missing the `src` part.